# How to refresh child ContentPage of TabbedPage in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Im using TabbedPage and encounter a problem: the ContentPage of each tab does not refresh when tabbed.I have a tab where I add item to cart and another tab to showing list of items have been added. Whenever I tabbed the list tab, it does not show new items that I added. Here my ViewModel of the showing list tab. The ListView.ItemSource is binding to FavoriteProducts

```
class FavoriteProductViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<FavoriteProductItem> favoriteProducts;

    public ObservableCollection<FavoriteProductItem> FavoriteProducts
    {
        get => favoriteProducts;
        set
        {
            favoriteProducts = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<FavoriteProduct> favoriteList;

    public ObservableCollection<FavoriteProduct> FavoriteList
    {
        get => favoriteList;
        set
        {
            favoriteList = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public FavoriteProductViewModel()
    {
        LoadData();
    }

    public async void LoadData()
    {
        var productList = await HomeService.Instance.GetAllProduct();
        FavoriteList = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteProduct>( await ProductService.Instance.GetFavoriteProductByCustomerID(Const.CurrentCustomerID));

        FavoriteProducts = new ObservableCollection<FavoriteProductItem>();
        if (productList != null && productList.Count > 0 && FavoriteList != null && FavoriteList.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var f in FavoriteList)
            {
                foreach (var p in productList)
                {
                    if (f.ProductID == p.ID)
                    {
                        FavoriteProducts.Add(new FavoriteProductItem
                        {
                            ID = p.ID,
                            DisplayName = p.DisplayName,
                            Price = p.Price,
                            DiscountPercent = p.DiscountPercent,
                            DiscountPrice = p.DiscountPrice,
                            Image1 = p.Image1,
                            Rating = p.Rating,
                            CommentCount = p.CommentCount,
                            IsSelected = false
                        });
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }           
    }
}
```

the added item will be add to FavoriteList via database. How can I refresh the ListView Tabbed Page?

Comment: are all your tabs using the same **instance** the VM?  If not there is no reason for them to update when changes are made.  You will need to write code to make them update

Comment: @Jason each of the tabs using different VM, but it seem like all of those VN was called as the same time when the app start. Can I do something about the Appearing event of the tab to make it refresh?

Comment: you can use the CurrentPageChanged event

Comment: @Jason How can I use it?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the **OnAppearing()** method of the page which display the list contains items you want to show.

Get all the items(Loaddata()) from database when page is about to display. like:

```
protected override OnAppearing()
{base.OnAppearing;
.
.
.//loaddata code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution by using the Appearing event for the tab I want to refresh. The event is like this:

```
private void FavoriteProductPage_Appearing(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            CurrentPage.BindingContext = new FavoriteProductViewModel();
        }
```